# How to drop multiple column names given in a list from Spark DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dynamic list which is created based on value of n.

```py
n = 3
drop_lst = ['a' + str(i) for i in range(n)]
df.drop(drop_lst)
```

But the above is not working.

**Note**:

My use case requires a dynamic list.

If I just do the below without list it works

```py
df.drop('a0','a1','a2')
```

How do I make drop function work with list?

Spark 2.2 doesn't seem to have this capability. Is there a way to make it work without using `select()`?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use the `*` operator to pass the contents of your list as arguments to `drop()`:

```py
df.drop(*drop_lst)
```

Comment: Thanks! what does the * operator do? Whats its significance?

Comment: The star unpacks the contents of an iterator if you place it to its left, ie. it produces the individual elements of your list.

Comment: This does not work for me, it gives: TypeError: drop() takes exactly 2 arguments (92 given). I might have an old version?

Comment: To answer my own question: I just checked, and in my version (1.6.2), the list method described here does not work.

Comment: Great solution!! Thanks

Comment: The solution works in ***python*** but not in ***scala*** for scala see the answer by @fox ghost beneath

Answer (score 14):

You can give column name as comma separated list e.g.

```
df.drop("col1","col11","col21")
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how drop specified number of consecutive columns in scala:

```
val ll = dfwide.schema.names.slice(1,5)
dfwide.drop(ll:_*).show
```

slice take two parameters star index and end index.

Answer (score -1):

Use simple loop:

```
for c in drop_lst:
   df = df.drop(c)
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score -6):

You can use `drop(*cols)` 2 ways .

1. `df.drop('age').collect()`
2. `df.drop(df.age).collect()`

Check the official documentation [DataFrame.drop](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=drop#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop)

Comment: what does .collect() do in this case?