# Add JSON object field to a JSON array field in the dataframe using scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Is there any method, where i can add a json object to already existing json object array:

I have a dataframe:

```
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|   name                  |       hit_songs                                         |  column1   |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|{"HomePhone":"34567002"} | [{"Phonetypecode":"PTC001"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC002"}] | value1     |
|{"HomePhone":"34567011"} | [{"Phonetypecode":"PTC021"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC022"}] |  value2    |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

I want a resulting dataframe as:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|   name                                                                                column1  
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|[ {"HomePhone":"34567002"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC001"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC002"} ] |  value1     |
|[ {"HomePhone":"34567011"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC021"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC022"} ] |   value2    |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------++------------+
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you show what you need in dataframes because I assume ultimately you want data in table format and not json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_union` function.

`name` is of type string, to convert this column to array type use `array`

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|name                    |hit_songs                                              |
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|{"HomePhone":"34567002"}|[{"Phonetypecode":"PTC001"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC002"}]|
|{"HomePhone":"34567011"}|[{"Phonetypecode":"PTC021"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC022"}]|
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+


scala> df.withColumn("name",array_union(array($"name"),$"hit_songs")).show(false) // Use array_union function, to join name string column with hit_songs array column, first convert name to array(name).
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|name                                                                             |hit_songs                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"HomePhone":"34567002"}, {"Phonetypecode":"PTC001"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC002"}]|[{"Phonetypecode":"PTC001"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC002"}]|
|[{"HomePhone":"34567011"}, {"Phonetypecode":"PTC021"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC022"}]|[{"Phonetypecode":"PTC021"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC022"}]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|name                    |dammy        |hit_songs                                              |
+------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|{"HomePhone":"34567002"}|{"aaa":"aaa"}|[{"Phonetypecode":"PTC001"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC002"}]|
|{"HomePhone":"34567011"}|{"bbb":"bbb"}|[{"Phonetypecode":"PTC021"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC022"}]|
+------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+


scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dammy: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hit_songs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)


scala> df.withColumn("name",array_union(array_union(array($"name"),$"hit_songs"),array($"dammy"))).show(false)

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|name                                                                             |dammy        |hit_songs                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"HomePhone":"34567002"}, {"Phonetypecode":"PTC001"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC002"}]|{"aaa":"aaa"}|[{"Phonetypecode":"PTC001"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC002"}]|
|[{"HomePhone":"34567011"}, {"Phonetypecode":"PTC021"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC022"}]|{"bbb":"bbb"}|[{"Phonetypecode":"PTC021"},{"Phonetypecode":"PTC022"}]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: what if we want to add as a third column?

Comment: Sir, actually i have more columns other than name and hit_songs.i want them to remain intact and this joined array column should be there.I have updated the question dataframe. please cheeck

Comment: ok, I have updated answer, use withColumn & use drop() function to drop not required columns.

Comment: let me check it

Comment: Throwing error:   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException cannot resolve 'array_union(array(entitymappingJoinA.`phonestruct11`), entitymappingJoinA.`phonestruct11`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function array_union should have been two arrays with same element type, but it's [array<struct<id:string,homephone:string,homephoneextension:string,workphone:string,workphoneextension:string,cellphone:string,cellphoneextension:string>>, struct<id:string,homephone:string,homephoneextension:string,workphone:string,workphoneextension:string,cellphone:string,cellphoneextension:string>];;

Comment: why we are putting dammy a part of array_union, we dont want  it in resulting array

Comment: you have asked me if you want to add another column to array , for that i have used dammy column to show you ..

Comment: for above issue use - array_union(array(entitymappingJoinA.phonestruct11), array(entitymappingJoinA.phonestruct11))

Comment: this is the recent error i got, both are arrays, idk why its not taking them    org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException cannot resolve 'array_union(array(entitymappingJoinA.`phonestruct11`), entitymappingOP.`phonestruct1`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function array_union should have been two arrays with same element type, but it's [array<struct<id:string,homephone:string,homephoneextension:string,workphone:string,workphoneextension:string,cellphone:string,cellphoneextension:string>>, array<struct<id:string,Phonetypecode:string,PhoneNumber:string,PhoneExtension:string>>];;

Comment: ```array_union``` function takes two parameters both parameter should be ```same data type```. in the above case you are passing two different datatypes.. thats why it is failing.

Comment: please have a look on the recent error that shows both are array of structs

Comment: Is the error coming because both arrays have structs with different no. and name of fields?

Comment: different datatypes

Comment: yeah one was array of structs and the other was only struct. thats why we created array of struct first and then array_union it with array of structs. so why is there an error

Comment: even you wrap second one inside array, still its datatype is not matched with the first one. because second one has less number of fields than the first one.

Comment: actually the array of structs is coming from different data frame and the struct is coming from differnet framework. I join these dataframes and then the resulting dataframe contains these two fields. now i want to combine them. any way out?

Comment: yes, try to convert both into json string .. then pass it to array_union .. it will work ..

Comment: what if i keep all the fields that are constituting those structs in the table. merge these tables and the create arrays or json from the resulting dataframe. then they would be from same type?

Comment: as long as both are same datatype it will work else it will fail.. may you can add your two dataframe schema to your question.

Comment: Sure Sir. I have a question, what if one of the arrays inside array_union is null. What if it is something like array_union(array(1,2,3),null). What would be the answer?

Comment: You have to make both arrays of same data type .. like this array_union($"value",array(lit("null").cast("int"))).as("a_union"), result is +-------------+
|a_union      |
+-------------+
|[1, 2, 3,]    |
+-------------+ in this last value is null.